# Numerical integration over an actual series, is this possible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration, numerical-methods

I was wondering about the following: 
Is there any clever way to evaluate integrals over a series?

Let me choose an example: $$\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(\cos(x))dx$$

where $P_n$ is the n-th Legendre-polynomial and assuming that this series whole thing there exists. Is there a smart way to get a numerical approximation for this?

The only thing that I could think of is to use some cut-off number $m$ so that you treat the series as a sum from $n=0$ to $m$. But I guess there are better ways to do it or is my suggestion actually what is done in those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a nice [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) like in this case :
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{1-2zt+t^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(z)t^n$$
you may get a closed form (for $\,z:=\cos(x)\,$ and $t=1$) :
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{1-2\cos(x)+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(\cos(x))$$
and formally :
\begin{align}
\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(\cos(x))dx&=\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi}\frac 1{\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}}dx\\
&=\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi}\frac 1{\sqrt{4\,\sin(x/2)^2}}dx\\
&=\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi}\frac 1{2\,\sin(x/2)}dx\\
&=\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\pi}\frac 1{4\,\sin(x/4)\cos(x/4)}dx\\
&=\left.\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac x4\right)\right)\right|_{\frac{2\pi}3}^{\pi}\\
&=\ln\frac 1{\frac 1{\sqrt{3}} }\\
&=\frac {\ln\,3}2\\
\end{align}

Comment: although you have given a nice solution to the exercise, it does no really answer my question of how to do this in general with numerical methods? I am interested in how numerical integration works for functions, that are given by a (double) series.

Comment: @Lipschitz: Well you wanted a clever way! When a generating function exists the clever way is to use it ! :-). I don't think there is a 'general method' : it depends much of the behavior of $P_n$ over the integration interval. You may have to invert integral and sum (eventually add a nonexistent parameter to assume convergence and so on...) but numerical integration of every term would have a non neglectable cost.

Comment: well, i mean there has to be something at least. cause most functions will be given by sum series representation and if numerical mathematics can't handle this problem, then it is pretty useless for complicated systems in nature.

Comment: @Lipschitz: here you are using Legendre polynomials that have plenty of properties that allow to use them in sums and integrals in a symbolic way as illustrated. Numerical integration should rather be used when no such orthogonal properties may be used... I mean that if you put your problem under this form it is for a reason (to simplify the work later) if this is just complicating the thing then I would rather compute the numerical integration at the start.

Comment: yeah and actually I am concerned with those kind of functions, but I just wanted to write down something, that you could use to show how numerical mathematics would tackle this problem. frankly, i did not gave much thought about it, whether you could actually integrate this thing analytically or not.

Comment: I mean the thing is the following: for most of all numerical methods I know, you need to be able to evaluate the function, but if this function is given by a complicated series, this will be impossible in general. so how can one proceed now?

Comment: @Lipschitz: I think that a nice problem for numerical integration is simply $\int \frac 1{x^4+1} dx$ over a finite range. In 2D like here you could simply use Simson for the numerical integration and compute the sum (reorganizing if needed). The residual problem here is that the terms will oscillate more and more so that Simson and other numerical methods could fail for large $n$ (that's why I don't see a general method...)

Comment: yeah, but this is an easy problem, because you are able to evaluate the function. It is getting interesting now, if you cannot do this

Comment: @Lipschitz: if you speak of $\int \frac 1{x^4+1} dx$ you will find many (including Vladimir Arnold I think) saying that it is better to do numerical integration in this case because the abstract function you will obtain is of no use while the numerical solution is very quick (and can be done mentally...).

Comment: okay, i agree with all you are saying, but the methods you are refering to just work, when we are able to evaluate the function. and this is the case for the integral that you have written down there. but what is the best method if this is not true, as in the case of a series that you cannot evaluate, that was my question?

Comment: @Lipschitz: one problem here is the weird oscillations for large $n$ that don't seem very practical for numerical integration (Monte Carlo methods would work but I am not sure that you want to introduce these at this point). Another method would be to search an approximation of the function : replace the $P_n$ by its main term like in stationary phase (not that it applies here...) supposing that the $P_n$ contributions are decreasing...

Comment: Actually, I do not see how Monte Carlo would work, since you also need to be able to evaluate your function for this one afaik, or am I wrong? Yes, this was actually the reason why I was going for the Legendre polynomials, since they have this awful oscillating behaviour, so they contain a lot of pathological properties that will immediately become important if a method is not useful in general.

Comment: @Lipschitz: The problem with Legendre $P_n$ is not only the weird oscillations but the fact that their amplitude is nearly constant so that any error (of course I supposed exact evaluation for M.C.) or unadapted numerical integration will be amplified. I fear I won't be able to help you on this : from my point of view when you start with a complicated problem, rewrite it (approximatively) using more elementary terms (like powers, exponentials, $P_n$'s and so on) then we should keep these terms (ev. neglect some of them) to the end...

Comment: We could integrate numerically (say) a difference with these perfect terms but not denature them. Well it's only my point of view...